# Using classes in Python

Tags: python, list, class, python-2.7

If I have 5 pieces of relevant data, I think it's fair to use a class in order to sort data effectively. However, I need to add these vars to a list.

If I have class "student(name, grade, attendance)", and I'm appending these values to a list, what would that look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# student class, inits with name and student id
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,grade, attendance):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.attendance = attendance
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# list of students    
students = []

# creates two students
s1 = Student('terry', 99, 99)
s2 = Student('jack', 42, 1)

# add students in the list
students.append(s1)
students.append(s2)
print students
```

Comment: How would this change if I had an unknown number of students that I had to pass through the student class?

Comment: You would simply loop through the students, then make each element to become an instance of students, then push to the students list.